# Managment / Removal (Define a 'public' space?)

Tags: juju, maas

Using Juju, and MaaS; Both installed onto the same machine. Using a happy mix of Physical and Virtual nodes.

I've found the documentation rather frustrating when it comes to networking.

I am looking to define a subnet as public, and have a majority of the DB networking performed over a specific vlan, and only expose the public (untaged) network to those that I allow.

Here's my problem; The [Documentation (https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/network-spaces)](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/network-spaces) lists commands that don't actually exist.

`juju spaces` Lists all of the default `space-0` and the subnets connected to the JuJu box, some of which I'd like to make private.

### Questions:

1. Do I have to remove a subnet before I add it to the *dmz* space?
2. How do I define a space as public?
3. Is there other documentation I could study, so I can see what I actually have control over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the documentation needs update. You can refer to https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/commands

The command to add space is

```
juju add-space <space-name>
```

There is no command to remove a space but you can move the subnets to other spaces. For example, if a subnet is in a space named 'internal', and you want to move that to another space 'admin', run

```
juju add-subnet <cidr> admin
```

The space settings should be automatically picked up by Juju if you've configured spaces in MAAS.